# Why couldn't R find the auto.arima function?

Tags: r, java

I am new to R. I encountered an error when I wanted to use the `auto.arima` function. The message was:

> could not find function "auto.arima"

I've installed the `forecast` package. I'm using R2.14.1 version and forecast 3.16 in windows 7 operating system. What can I do?

If I could use the `auto.arima` function in R and get the best result model, I want to call the `auto.arima` method in my Java project. How would I use the R library in java project?

Comment: Have you loaded the package e.g., `library(forecast)`   ?

Comment: I've load it. I loaded forecast_3.16 package from package menu. I get a message "package ‘forecast’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked". Then I try to test auto.arima function but the function is still not found. I also try to load the package with install.packages("forecast") code but I get an error message >> package ‘forecast’ is not available (for R version 2.14.1). What's wrong?

Comment: Thank you all for the tips. I've been used auto.arima function by library(forecast) and reinstalled R before.

Answer (score 3):

As the others pointed out: You have downloaded the package with `install.packages()` or from the menu but you did not *load* the package. This is done by `library(forecast)` or `require(forecast)`. You can obtain single functions as well with the command: `package::function()` just like: `forecast::auto.arima()`. So much for a little clarification. If you need a graphical user interface (it makes life easier) check out Rstudio [Rstudio](http://www.rstudio.org) or R commander  `install.packages(Rcmdr)` or rJava proposed by Zach.

Answer (score 0):

1. As @Jeromy Anglim says: `library(forecast)`
2. http://www.rforge.net/rJava/

Answer (score 0):

When installing, make sure you mark the "Install Dependencies" option.

Answer (score 0):

To use the auto.arima package, you need to install the package "quadprog".  Install that package first and put forecast into library and you should be ok

Answer (score 0):

You need to do the following steps

```
install.packages("xts")
install.packages("forecast", dependencies = TRUE)
library(forecast)
```

This worked for me.